# Array Declaration and Initialization in If Statement Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

So I am trying to access the contents of an array in my code that is initialized and decalred in an if statement.

Here's the code

```
        String Columns[]=new String[records.size()];
        if(records.size()==3){
            Columns={"Forename","Surname","Salary"};
        }
        else{
            Columns={"Forename","Surname"};
        }
        String Query[]=new String[records.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<records.size(); i++)
        {
            Query[i]="UPDATE table SET "+Columns[i]+"='"+records.get(i)+"' WHERE StaffID="+id;
        }
```

I get the errors 'illegal start of expression' and 'not a statement.' So when I try and define it in the if statement like so...

```
        if(records.size()==3){
            String Columns[]={"Forename","Surname","Salary"};
        }
        else{
            String Columns[]={"Forename","Surname"};
        }
        String Query[]=new String[records.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<records.size(); i++)
        {
            Query[i]="UPDATE table SET "+Columns[i]+"='"+records.get(i)+"' WHERE StaffID="+id;
        }
```

I get this instead: Cannot find symbol Columns.

Any suggestions as to how I could get this code to compile?

All feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just declare `Columns` before your `if` statement

Comment: Variables have *scope*. If you declare them in a block, they only exist in that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a declaration of the variable beforehand:

```
String[] columns;
if (records.size()) {
    // set values
} else {
    // set other values
}
// do code logic
```